# ORA-01036 when calling Oracle PL/SQL function with Node.js

Tags: node.js, oracle, node-oracledb

i'm trying to call this sql statement

```
 let sql: string = 'BEGIN :ret := PAC_AGE_WEB.FUN_ATIVA_FAT_ELETRONICA_AEL(:i_cod_un_cons, :i_num_cli, :i_cpu_os, :i_seq_oper_os, :i_seq_ger_os); END;';
  //
  let bindvars: oracledb.BindParameters = {
    i_cod_un_cons: Number.parseFloat(numeroUc),
    i_num_cli: Number.parseFloat(numeroCliente),
    i_cpu_os: codigoCpu.toString(),
    i_seq_oper_os: Number.parseFloat(numeroSeqOper),
    i_seq_ger_os: Number.parseFloat(numeroSeqGer),
    result: { type: oracledb.STRING, dir: oracledb.BIND_OUT, maxSize: 4000 }
  };
  //
  super.execute(sql, bindvars, autoCommit, connection, (errorAtivaFaturaEletronica, resultAtivaFaturaEletronica) => {
```

and i'm getting the folowing error => Error: ORA-01036: illegal variable name/number errorNum: 1036, offset: 0

The variables types are:
i_cod_un_cons: float, 
i_num_cli: float, 
i_cpu_os: string, 
i_seq_oper_os: float, 
i_seq_ger__os: float

Comment: Your SQL statement refers to `:ret` but your `bindvars` has a property named `result`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved by changing ':ret' to ':result'.